# How to retrieve list from DB to front-end with AutoMapper

Tags: list, automapper

After changing the mapping to Automapper, only an empty list is sent through the endpoint.

Initially I had an endpoint that retrieved all employees with info including a list with every course each employee had taken. This was with manual mapping between entities & Dto.

//From startup.cs in Configure

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Employee, Models.EmployeeCoursesDto>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Employee, Models.EmployeeDto>();
                cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeCourses, Models.EmployeeCoursesDto>();
            });
```

//From Employee entity

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        //Gen new Id key in DB when object created
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeCourses> EmployeeCourses { get; set; }
        = new List<EmployeeCourses>();
   }
}

//From employee Dto
public class EmployeeDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmployeeCoursesDto> EmployeeCourses { get; set; }
        = new List<EmployeeCoursesDto>();
    }
}

//Endpoint in controller
[HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult GetAllEmployees()
        {
            var employeeEntities = _employeeInfoRepository.GetEmployees();
            var results = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<EmployeeDto>>(employeeEntities);

            return Ok(results);
        }

//From Irepository
IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees();

//From repository
 public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            return _context.Employees.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
        }
```

I expected output all employees with all datafileds, including their list of courses. 
The output is all fields with data, except the list of courses which is "0" when running with a breakpoint, and in Postman it shows as only:
  "id": 2,
        "name": "Test Person",
        "title": "Bus Driver",
        "numberOfCourses": 0,
        "employeeCourses": [],
        "totalAchievedHoursAuditor": 0,
        "totalAchievedHoursAccountant": 51,
        "courseBalanceAccountant": null,
        "courseBalanceAuditor": null

However, if I try another endpoint only for retrieving a specific course, or a list of courses, the data show correctly. Seems there are an issue with mapping the employees & courses at the same time?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, not Automapper, but my Linq statement:

return _context.Employees.Include(c => c.EmployeeCourses).ToList();

Please close this thread. Thanks for the reply Lucian Bargaoanu & have a great weekend.